# JS Count # of Differences in 2 Objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

I am trying to compare 2 objects and return # of different elements in the array. 
Originally I am thinking firstly sort the object by its key length, and read from the maxLength. But then I notice the min-length object may also contain some unique keys. e.g.

```
var max_obj = { a: aa, b: bb, c: cc, d: dd }
var min_obj = { a: aa, b: bb, z: zz }
```

So I loop again in min_obj for any missing key, but as the object expands, it seems horrible (still O(n) but image 100000 keys in it?). So the code looks like this:

```
// innerLength: count # of diff in a specific object key
// maxObj/minObj: originally I sort them by key.length, but from this point this seems useless
      for(var t in maxObj) {
            if (!(t in minObj)) {
                diffCount += innerLength(maxObj[t]);
            } else if (!elementEqualFn(maxObj[t], minObj[t])) {
                diffCount += Math.abs(innerLength(maxObj[t]) - innerLength(minObj[t]));;
            } 
        } 
        // inefficient, but we need to count those unique ones in minObj as well
        for(var t in minObj) {
            if (!(t in maxObj)) {
                diffCount += innertLength(minObj[t]);
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any suggestion/idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to check every key, I believe you cannot do it faster.